# It seems some image links in the posts are not working any more

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, site-enhancement, image

I have noticed that previously-working images in some posts now flickers for a second before eyes and are hidden immediately.  While inspecting such problematic image links in the posts, I have noticed some discrepancies, like the link Markdown structure in the post is:

```
[![image description][ID]][ID]
```

Removing the second ID from the markup and additional square brackets works, like changing the above code into:

```
![image description][ID]
```

Were there some site maintenance tasks which have broken some posts' embedded links? I feel this problem must be escalated, because all image links in all posts should be cross-validated now.

**EDIT**

Platform details :

```
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Browser details :

```
Google Chrome   121.0.6167.85 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
Revision    3f98d690ad7e59242ef110144c757b2ac4eef1a2-refs/branch-heads/6167@{#1539}
OS  Linux
JavaScript  V8 12.1.285.26
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /app/extra/chrome --disable-features=WebAssemblyTrapHandler,DesktopPWAsRunOnOsLogin --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU
Executable Path /app/extra/chrome
Profile Path    /home/null/.var/app/com.google.Chrome/config/google-chrome/Default
Active Variations   78ce0fb-ca7d8d80
be9ac099-12ede6a2
8c693aa5-ca7d8d80
692c4a33-477edaa
50eef52b-a79d803f
b0a56918-ca7d8d80
b05e1e6c-ca7d8d80
5f8b0593-ca7d8d80
19cad42d-ca7d8d80
f301790-ca7d8d80
b334488c-ca7d8d80
eddd0d82-7723ede9
aba1243e-82d6e34b
e18619cd-ca7d8d80
87f33ad6-377be55a
65df225-ca7d8d80
3095aa95-3f4a17df
5e26295f-ca7d8d80
521a59ad-f9a43703
6d3329df-ca7d8d80
b4fb8450-ca7d8d80
cba02cf0-ca7d8d80
87ccf3f3-ca7d8d80
82ada734-ca7d8d80
44666d99-ca7d8d80
9c4e9263-12ede6a2
ddb8ff70-ca7d8d80
7fc2c6dc-bf95fb92
b2cff759-b2cff759
6f55e1a1-377be55a
f8411335-ca7d8d80
a582a1b8-5ad3f43d
669a7db8-ca7d8d80
494e2c16-ca7d8d80
ce9b8a32-4d2fac87
d92d97b4-ca7d8d80
ae1924b1-2840b4af
e88c95b8-ca7d8d80
c5109773-ca7d8d80
8eb498bd-ca7d8d80
26665953-ca7d8d80
27f750c-ca7d8d80
1d865dc8-65334638
3fd33f16-ca7d8d80
d9384a1d-ca7d8d80
62f811c6-ca7d8d80
6b9250af-ca7d8d80
c272f203-12ede6a2
95a095bd-12ede6a2
f6264095-12ede6a2
bacf219a-ca7d8d80
8d182722-377be55a
910af27f-694968cf
d4d0c0cb-ca7d8d80
7999ec3c-ca7d8d80
784a7e92-ca7d8d80
fc9ceed7-ca7d8d80
d664a1aa-ca7d8d80
dfc2d5d9-ca7d8d80
2b4e7fda-4a4621d9
ea90e0df-91a3a8c2
39f17c85-ef1fc9f7
4bc95f1e-ee3cba41
84f2bb65-eafdd735
16c46fd0-485ec16e
b8b71ed9-dabe7183
ab1d6da3-ca7d8d80
dcceede7-f13ce319
4a8bb706-1f8c5973
2e89c181-377be55a
fa33ceb5-2b6ed456
cb87f652-33c3eba5
314a184e-ca7d8d80
da493d3c-ca7d8d80
72bafd3e-12ede6a2
3ed7dfc4-ca7d8d80
ea9324c5-ca7d8d80
3ed94085-b59f7663
5d1017fe-ca7d8d80
94ea64fd-ca7d8d80
59a12fbe-6cf8754c
bb73ab6c-7b676c3b
ea23a088-377be55a
8c584bf0-ca7d8d80
349863a7-ca7d8d80
bff0815b-ca7d8d80
c88cdb84-ca7d8d80
45a2f2f-4993f9d1
83514069-6edc92c7
dca2449f-ca7d8d80
137f6fe-4d2fac87
86362250-ca7d8d80
36c3226a-377be55a
b88dc83e-ca7d8d80
4ea303a6-11610cc8
4190c9c9-ca7d8d80
258151b3-ca7d8d80
5af3ddb7-5419e7bd
f1efb311-1f8c5973
d7d493f4-905ae853
f3b6291d-ca7d8d80
a6caa730-ca7d8d80
1edcddf4-31889cb4
278baf51-387c1f0e
e2e21759-ca7d8d80
c1771bc6-ca7d8d80
c65eafdb-377be55a
3dc7b4fe-377be55a
f9be514e-ca7d8d80
5f656ab9-377be55a
ea0d881d-ca7d8d80
3f752d-ca7d8d80
fd4b313c-f23d1dea
b2615123-377be55a
1918000d-e2351cfe
cd1a6113-9abe4278
23226e84-12ede6a2
3797f84b-ca7d8d80
4d3350df-ca7d8d80
f43e9210-377be55a
ef85228a-203e66b8
c845dfe2-d0134b67
83d1a239-377be55a
ce43899a-377be55a
ec637609-ef8c3c9a
4e762e93-ca7d8d80
94f1fa38-ca7d8d80
3fc87288-ca7d8d80
6cfccc3-ca7d8d80
90860314-2155f233
494d8760-52325d43
eadcacdf-6bdfffe7
7b2873c2-f9e34637
3ac60855-486e2a9c
f48c01d3-c9708222
63dcb6a3-58ca20a
e706e746-7da8925a
f296190c-9ce370dd
4442aae2-a90023b1
f690cf64-6bdfffe7
ed1d377-e1cc0f14
75f0f0a0-4ad60575
710c3f90-6bdfffe7
e2b18481-6e3b1976
e7e71889-e1cc0f14
67ca41ce-ca7d8d80
858aa29b-377be55a
bea4a9c2-ca7d8d80
1ae0f6fa-ca7d8d80
5a18fe50-ca7d8d80
542d15b1-377be55a
ff1dade5-12ede6a2
f38ef081-12ede6a2
22baf79f-ca7d8d80
3906c665-ca7d8d80
dd08905f-f637b7e7
6dcf9601-ca7d8d80
c55491ea-4b0b636c
a38f69b3-f23d1dea
3bd26dba-ad071dfc
8d549a7a-5fe72c56
```

So it must be a browser/OS problem.

Comment: The difference between the two formats is whether the image is also a link. The flickering might be a CSS-type issue. Can you post browser and platform details, and link to a post that you've fixed? (Or better, to one that's still broken.) If someone can confirm the bug, I'll escalate.

Comment: The couple posts I've fixed is [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797551/nature-of-absorption-spectra-peaks-similar-profile-in-dimethyl-sulfide-c-2h) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797642/determining-a-gapped-hamiltonian-from-correlation-function). But I've reverted now my first edit back to image & link format, and strangely it works now too. Seems was a temporal issues, like CSS or something ?

Comment: Seems that this bug is only reproduced in my home computer & google browser, I will edit post for adding details for support about my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason of this issue. I have some AdBlocker plugin active in my Google Chrome browser. Strangely, it interprets embedded image links of "double ID format" as an Ads (probably because you can click on them), and removes them from the page. Disabling AdBlocker solves the issue. So seems that what is Ad and what is not Ad,- hard to guess these days. Anyway, maybe this info will help somebody.